# Build Failed before adding code. How is this possible?

Tags: build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I don't understand why I am getting a "run build" and "build failed" error when I have not added or deleted any code.

I tried the "invalidate cache/restart" as well as "rebuild project" but the error still occurs.

The first is below:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0.9

The second error is

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0

.

These errors are occurring in the initial build as I am attempting to do my 1st class assignment. My accountability partner and I attempted to figure it out but he has a Mac (Maybe that's why he couldn't reproduce the errors) I cleared the cache, restarted the build several times. Updated Gradle. Doubled checked settings. etc.

I am at a loss for a resolution.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the grammar, I should hire you as my editor. The problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was traced back to my machine not having enough RAM.

Meh, I'm a coding newbie this is all apart of the learning process as well as changing career fields.